# Variance of urn problem with replacement and color switching

Tags: probability, variance, coupon-collector

**Objective:** I am trying to calculate the variance for each number of draws $k$ for an urn problem (analogous to coupon collector's).

**Problem description:**
Imagine a urn, initially completely filled with $n$ marbles of color green. Define that 1) each time that a green colored marble is drawn from the urn another marble of color red is put back instead of the green marble; and 2) if a red colored marble is drawn it is simply put back into the urn. Under the above conditions, what is the variance for the probability of drawing a red marble after k draws?

**Related questions:**
Two questions, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235943/urn-problem-with-multiple-drawings-and-conditional-replacement?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160584/formula-for-urn-model-with-replacement-and-color-switching?rq=1), give the probability of obtaining a red marble after k draws as

\begin{equation}\boxed{E(X)=1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k-1}}\end{equation}

**Additional information**
My attempt to calculate the variance goes along the lines of assuming that drawing a red ball corresponds to $X=1$, and a green marble to a $X=0$. Then I use the definition of variance as
$$
Var(X)=p_r(1-E(X))^2+p_g(0-E(X))^2
$$
where $p_r$ and $p_g$ are the probability of drawing a red and green ball, respectively. I assume, but am not sure, that this would correspond to $E(X)$ and $1-E(X)$? If so, the variance becomes
$$
Var(X)=E(X)(1-E(X))^2+(1-E(X))(0-E(X))^2
$$
By simplification I have reached this expression
$$
Var(X)=\left(\left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{(k - 1)} - 1\right)^2\times\left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{(k - 1)} - \left(\left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{(k - 1)} - 1\right)\times\left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^{(2k - 2)}
$$
I think that my confusion stems from the fact that in this particular problem we are computing "the probability of a probability". Thank you in advance for any help.

**Update**
I have compared the analytic mean and variance of the equation given by Henry against 30 randomly generated runs, with $k=600$ and $n=50$. As you can see in Fig.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxDMY.jpg) the mean (red line) and the confidence interval (2$\sigma$) match the numerical runs (black lines) very well, except for a large value of $k$ (but this is because the distribution is not symmetric).

[[image: k vs probability with mean (red line) and <span class=]$2\sigma$ standard deviation" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPS3f.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an occupancy/coupon-collector/birthday type  problem.  I would have thought variance would be:

$$\frac1n\left(1- \frac1{n}\right)^{(k - 1)}+\left(1- \frac1{n}\right) \times\left(1- \frac2{n}\right)^{(k - 1)} - \left(1- \frac1{n}\right)^{2(k - 1)}$$

and if $k=2$ (i.e. you are about to draw for the second time) this correctly gives $0$ since the only possibility for the probability is $\frac1n$ with no variance,  while your expression seems to give a variance of  $\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}$

---

*Added:*

I think the probability that *"the probability for the $k$th draw is $\frac xn$"* is $\dfrac{S_2(k-1,x) \, n!}{n^{k-1} \,(n-x)!}$ where $S_2(,)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind, so for each $k$ you could add these up and find the $2.5\%$ and $97.5\%$ cumulative probability points. But it might be easier to use a recurrence: $P_{k,n}(\frac {x}n) = \frac{n-x+1}{n}P_{k-1,n}(\frac {x-1}n) +\frac{x}{n}P_{k-1,n}(\frac {x}n)$

The following R code graphically illustrates the distinction between a $\mu\pm2\sigma$ interval in blue, and an interval based on having the probability of being above or below each no more than $2.5\%$ using the actual probabilities in red; remember the intervals are vertical and the the probabilities of drawing a green marble are of the form $\frac xn$ where $x$ and $n$ are integers, leading to the steps in the blue lines.

For $n=50$ balls, the red and blue lines are reasonably close up to $k=138$ draws, but for $k \ge 139$ draws then the $\mu+2\sigma$ values exceed $1$, unhelpful when this is supposed to bound *"the probability of drawing a red marble"*. For $k \ge 215$, the probability that *"the probability of drawing a red marble is $1$"* exceeds $0.5$, i.e. the median of the distribution is also the maximum of the distribution.

```
balls <- 50
maxdraws <- 600
probs <- matrix(0, nrow=balls, ncol=maxdraws)
probs[1, 2] <- 1
probsaverage <- c(0, 1/balls)
probslower <- c(0, 1/balls)
probsupper <- c(0, 1/balls)
for (draw in 3:maxdraws){
  probs[ 1, draw] <- probs[ 1, draw-1] * 1/balls
  probs[-1, draw] <- probs[-1, draw-1] * (2:balls)/balls + 
                     probs[-balls, draw-1] * ((balls-1):1)/balls
  probsaverage[draw] <- sum(probs[,draw] * (1:balls) / balls)
  probslower[draw] <- min(which(cumsum(probs[,draw]) >   0.025)) / balls
  probsupper[draw] <- min(which(cumsum(probs[,draw]) >=  0.975)) / balls
  }
probmean <- function(n,k){
  1 - (1-1/n)^(k-1)
  }
probvar <- function(n,k){
  1/n * (1-1/n)^(k-1) + (1-1/n) * (1-2/n)^(k-1) - (1-1/n)^(2*k-2) 
  }

plot(probsaverage, type="l")
lines(probslower, col="blue")
lines(probsupper, col="blue")
draws <- 1:maxdraws
lines(probmean(balls, draws), col="grey")
lines(probmean(balls, draws) - 2*sqrt(probvar(balls, draws)), col="red")
lines(probmean(balls, draws) + 2*sqrt(probvar(balls, draws)), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any textbook proof of this? I realized that this distribution is skewed negatively for higher values of $k$, and I did not account for this in my numerical verification; I simply added $\pm 2\sigma$ to the mean value. Can you tell me how to account for this effect (as I am normally used to symmetric distributions)?

Comment: I have added a chart on the intervals.  Remember that at each point, up to $1$ in $20$ simulations might be expected to be outside a $95\%$ interval